# How to encapsulate JavaScript code as jQuery plugin or other solution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a following piece of code on a few pages, and I'll need it on even more:

```
        $('.editable-textbox').live('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }).live('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
```

There're a few drawbacks of it:

- the code doesn't imply what it does. What it does is: prevents form submittion when enter is hit on control with `.editable-textbox` class + control is blurred
- of course code duplication

I just wonder: is there a way to refactor it to have something like this:

```
$('.editable-textbox').supressFormSubmitOnEnter();
```

with jQuery.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.

```
$.fn.supressFormSubmitOnEnter = function() {
    return this.live('keypress', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }).live('keyup', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
};
```

You should give the [Plugin Authoring Guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) a read.

Also, it could be written much terser...

```
$.fn.supressFormSubmitOnEnter = function() {
    return $(document).on('keypress keyup', this, function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                $(this).blur();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
};
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C6EZ8/).

Answer (score -1):

You've got a great resource in the [jQuery Docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)